# Error in : Only strings can be converted to symbols in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to include a function in a shiny app and when I ran it I'm getting this error:

`Warning: Error in : Only strings can be converted to symbols`

The function works by itself, although it can be improved and simplified. I tried using `sym` and `ensym` but it didn't work. I'm also trying to understand what are the strings and symbols that are causing this issue.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(questionr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(haven)

fre <- function(var) {
    
    var <- rlang::ensym(var)
    
    abc <- questionr::na.rm(dat[, rlang::as_string(var)])
    abc <- questionr::freq(abc, total = TRUE, na.last = TRUE, digits = 2)
    abc <- cbind(Label = rownames(abc), abc)
    abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "n", "Frequency")
    abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "%", "Percent")
    abc <- tidyr::separate(abc, Label, into = c("Value", "Label"), sep = "] ")
    row.names(abc) <- NULL
    abc <- abc %>% dplyr::mutate(Value = gsub("[[:punct:]]", '', Value)) %>% dplyr::select(Label, Value, Frequency, Percent)
    abc
}


dat <- read_spss("http://staff.bath.ac.uk/pssiw/stats2/SAQ.sav")


ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel(" "),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("var1", "Frequency Table", choices = names(dat), selected = NULL)
        ),

        mainPanel(
           verbatimTextOutput("fretab")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$fretab <- renderPrint({
        fre(input$var1)
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Instead of `selected = NULL` can you pass `names(dat)[1]`

Comment: I tried changing this, but it didn't work

Comment: Isn't the variable 'var1'

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, good catch. But it doesn't work still.

Comment: can you check the solution posted below.

Comment: @TyperWriter shiny `selectInput`s are character vectors, so you don't need all the `tidyverse` "magic" where the function arguments are passed as symbols and not as the (character) variable names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `as_string`.  It can be changed to

```
fre <- function(var) {
  var_str1 <- var
  var <- rlang::ensym(var)
  
  abc <- questionr::na.rm(dat[, var_str1])
  abc <- questionr::freq(abc, total = TRUE, na.last = TRUE, digits = 2)
  abc <- cbind(Label = rownames(abc), abc)
  abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "n", "Frequency")
  abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "%", "Percent")
  abc <- tidyr::separate(abc, Label, into = c("Value", "Label"),
        sep = "] ")
  row.names(abc) <- NULL
  abc <- abc %>% dplyr::mutate(Value = gsub("[[:punct:]]", '', Value)) %>% 
        dplyr::select(Label, Value, Frequency, Percent)
  abc
}
```

with that change, the output would be

[image]